# Excel for Mac VBA - SQL Server INSERT statement for QueryTables

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, database

I have been working with Excel for Mac on a program that has tens of thousands of lines of code in VBA and is used across both Windows & Mac. I am able to successfully import information into the program using the QueryTables object, but I cannot get a SQL INSERT statement to execute. Is there any way to INSERT using QueryTables or is this the only way execute a command like this against the database? I have downloaded the Actual ODBC drivers for SQL Server that are compatible, but have not used them at all.

```
    If colInsertCustomers.Count > 0 Then
        sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblCustomersStage "
        sql = sql & cust.SQLFields
        sql = sql & " VALUES "
        For Each cust In colInsertCustomers
            sql = sql & cust.SQLValues & ","
        Next cust
        sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 1) ' Remove the last comma
        sql = sql & ";"
        qt.CommandText = sql
        qt.Refresh
    End If
```

I have tested the SQL generated by the above code and the SQL string (sql) that it generates, works to put data into the database (using Azure Data Studio). But every time that I get to qt.Refresh, it fails with the INSERT statement.

**For clarification**

*qt* is a validly initialized QueryTable that has a functional connection to the database and is able to execute multiple SELECT statements against the database.

*SQLFields* returns the list of fields to INSERT including brackets & parentheses

*SQLValues* returns the list of values aligned with SQLFields including commas, appropriate tick marks, and parentheses

cust is a CCustomer object that has too many properties and methods to list, but it is functional as well.

EDIT: Here is the connection string and definition of qt with obvious things obfuscated.

```
Set qt = ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;" & _
            "SERVER=myserver.database.windows.net;" & _
            "Database=mydb;UID=$;", _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```

EDIT 2: As a side-note, the Actual driver is able to connect, and execute these statements through Microsoft Query (Data Tab -> Get External Data -> SQL Server ODBC) without a problem. But when I try to record a macro while using this, I get nothing recorded. The connection string created by Microsoft Query is:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=myserver.database.windows.net;UID=myname;PWD=mypwd;APP=Microsoft Excel;WSID=my-computer;DATABASE=mydb;
```

Comment: Aside from being a huge SQL Injection problem (avoid [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)), your [insert statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) isn't being constructed correctly. The normal syntax is `insert schemaName.tableName (column_list) values (value_list)` while yours is missing the brackets around both the column names and the values to be inserted.

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not describe my SQL statement clearly enough. It is correct and works correctly when inserted into a program like Azure Data Studio. Those function calls (SQLFields & SQLValues) provide the parentheses and everything required including the brackets. Would you mind describing what a 'huge SQL injection problem' is though?

Comment: Thank you for the head's up on the SQL injection, pretty low threat in this application, but could become a bigger deal when we get more direct user input in the future. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I determined through the course of study on this issue that it is not possible to advance an Insert Statement through the QueryTable object in VBA. Although MSQuery works to insert from within Excel Mac, it does not have an exposed VBA object to allow this manipulation. I have chosen to move development to a Windows PC, I know that there are non-free solutions through two separate ODBC drivers that interact with SQL Server, this was one bridge too far for using the Mac (as much as I love it).